# Function to block duplicate usernames in database when true, inserts names into database when true

Tags: php, mysql

I made this function to prevent duplicate usernames in my mysql database when registering. If it returns false then the name can be made:

```
public function nameTaken($username){

    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE name = :name');

    $statement->execute(array('name' => $username));

    $res = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    $exists = array_pop($res);

    if ($exists > 0) {

        echo 'user already exists';

        return;

    } else {
        //the name can be made
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I tested it, even when it echo'd that users already exist and didn't return false, the username from the post request were still inserted into my database. Here is my function to insert into my database :

```
public function insert($table, $parameters){

    $sql = sprintf(

        'insert into %s (%s) values (%s)',

        $table,

        implode(', ', array_keys($parameters)),

        ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($parameters))

    );

    try {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $statement->execute($parameters);

    }   catch (Exception $e) {

        die('something went wrong');

    }

}
```

and here is my controller that gets the post requests to to register a name

```
<?php

$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if(!$app['database']->nameTaken($_POST['username'])){

    $app['database']->insert('users', [

        'name' => $_POST['username'],

        'password' => $hash

    ]);
};
```

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: The only reliable way to prevent duplicates is to have a `UNIQUE` index on any columns that *must* be unique and to deal with the resulting errors if you attempt to insert a duplicate record. Any code that tests counts is vulnerable to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). This is part 1 of my 29,342 part series on how writing login systems is really hard.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: I'm just learning the language right now and I'll get into frameworks after I've built a few things with raw php. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: That comes across as "I'm just learning how to drive now, so I'll look at buying a pre-made car after I've finished making this one out of wood." Frameworks are the best way to learn PHP, they'll not only show you how it's done at a high level, organizationally, but will give you more than ample opportunity to dig deeper into the stack to understand more fundamentals *if and when* you want to. Going from the ground up forces you to absorb a decade of lessons before you can build a truly secure application. It's just not practical these days.

Comment: If this login system is being used by actual people you have considerable responsibility to do this properly. Even the tiniest, most innocent mistake can be punished severely by an attacker: Often all it takes is a single slip and someone can crack your application wide open, steal all your data, or compromise your site with hostile code. Frameworks are battle tested and, should a vulnerability arise, you'll at least get some advance warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return true` when the username is taken, otherwise your if statement will match null and false:

```
if(!$app['database']->nameTaken($_POST['username'])){
```

`return;` is the same as `return null;` which is "falsy" (loosely equivalent to false).

Comment: thanks a lot, It's working now. I'm still a beginner.